# How to create a new stereo mix from one channel in Premiere pro cs5.5

Tags: audio, premiere, cs5

I have a video with stereo audio, but one channel is completely silent. So the audio only plays on the left stereo. How is it possible to duplicate the left channel and create a new stereo mix for the same clip? Or alternatively force the sound in a mono audio track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey try the audio effect Fill left or Fill right!
(I use a zoom h4n and have to constantly do that )
http://www.mediacollege.com/adobe/premiere/pro/audio/fill.html !

Happy editing!
(remember fireballs always make video better!)